# Deploy .Exe via Web

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, setup-deployment, openfin

I've an HTML5 application packaged into OpenFin environment. The complete package is inside an .Exe executable that we wish to ship to end users.

We tried to create a link to the executable that could be downloaded from a web link - but seems most of the company' security permissions environments/firewalls block .Exe file downloads.

Our requirement is to ship the .EXE file (we do not have certain files - so may not be able to effectively create a clickonce deployment package)

Is there a better way, even using ClickOnce to ship the .Exe via web url?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap exe into a zip and can ship..